# Values concatenating inside if condition

Tags: javascript, concatenation

Edit: For the sake of simplicity, consider following code:

```
var z = {x: 1, y: 1};

console.log(z.x+5 + ' ' + z.y+5);
```

Why output is (6,15) instead of (6,6)?

Before edit: I have following function:

```
function findPath(startX, startY, goalX, goalY){
    var queue = [],
        candidates = [],
        path = [];

    queue.push({x: startX, y: startY, searchDistance: 0, hasBeenSearched: true});

    fillQueue();

    function fillQueue(){
  setInnerHTML(queue[0].x, queue[0].y, '.');
        for(var i=-1; i<=1; i++){
            if(queue[0].x + i < 0 || queue[0].x + i >  boardHeight - 1){
                continue;
            }

            for(var j=-1; j<=1; j++){

                if(queue[0].y + j < 0 || queue[0].y + j > boardWidth - 1){
                    continue;
                }
                if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                    continue;
                }
                if(cells[queue[0].x + i][queue[0].y + j].type.blockMovement == true || findCell(queue[0].x + i, queue[0].y + j).hasBeenSearched == true){
                    console.log(queue[0].x + i + ' ' +  queue[0].y + j)
                    continue;
                }

                if((queue[0].x + i == goalX) && (queue[0].y + j == goalY)){
        setInnerHTML(queue[0].x + i, queue[0].y + j, '.');
                    candidates.push(queue[0]);
                    candidates.push({x: queue[0].x + i, y:  queue[0].y + j, searchDistance: queue[0].searchDistance + 1, hasBeenSearched: true});
                    //fillPath();
                    return path;
                }

                queue.push({x: queue[0].x + i, y: queue[0].y + j, searchDistance: queue[0].searchDistance + 1, hasBeenSearched: true}); 

            }
        }

        candidates.push(queue.shift());

        if(queue.length > 0){
            setTimeout(fillQueue, 0);
        }else{
            return 'no path found';
        }

        function findCell(x,y){
            for(var i=0; i<queue.length; i++){
                if(queue[i].x == x && queue[i].y == y){
                    return queue[i];
                }else if(i == queue.length - 1 && (queue[i].x != x || queue[i].y != y)){
                    return {hasBeenSearched: false};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is part of pathfinding algorithm I've been rewriting lately and I have following problem. Inside inner for loop, when this condition `findCell(queue[0].x + i, queue[0].y + j).hasBeenSearched == true` is being checked, values of second parameter `queue[0].y` and `j` are concatenated instead of just being added, while same condition for first parameter works correctly (values there are added). I'm trying to figure that out for several hours now and I have no idea what is going on. Both values `queue[0].y` and `j` are numbers(I checked it by console logging `typeof` them), and should be added just like similiar values in first paremeter. Any help with pointing me out what I did wrong will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/Furmanus/pen/LkXVwO/?editors=0011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS expressions are evaluated left-to-right. By the time it reaches that last `+`, it's evaluating `('6 1' + 5)`.

Put the last part in parentheses to force it to be evaluated separately: `console.log(z.x+5 + ' ' + (z.y+5))`.

You can also log multiple things using parentheses, which will avoid this problem: `console.log(z.x+5, z.y+5)`.

Comment: It wasn't exactly answer I was expecting, but it's good and correct answer - I just asked wrong question. Code was indeed broken and it was broken in a place I didn't expected it to be - anyway I still learned something new! So thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the arguments of the `findCell()` function are always Numbers.

The only place where there is a string is:

```
console.log(queue[0].x + i + ' ' +  queue[0].y + j)
```

This prints a string because sum is calculated from left to right.

Let's do it step by step:

1. queue[0].x + i are two numbers, and they are summed, and they oroduces a number (let's call it `xi`

So now our operation is:

```
console.log(xi + ' ' +  queue[0].y + j)
```

2. `xi` is a Number, and it is summed to `' '` which is a string. They produce a string (this is how JS does casting)

From here on, you sum strings and numbers, so first of all `queue[0].y` is casted to string and it is concatenated, then `j` is casted to string too and concatenated in the same way.

Solution is to force the precedence of operators:

```
console.log(queue[0].x + i + ' ' +  (queue[0].y + j))
```

**TL;DR**: the code is good, just the `console.log` is broken

Comment: No, `console.log` is fine; the code is broken. It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate the two values, the second one is converted to a string.

Instead, use:

```
var z = {x: 1, y: 1};
console.log(z.x+5 + ' ' + parseInt(z.y+5));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dovLgt5d/)